# Customize Soap Web Service Response Based On Context

Tags: xml, soap, web, service, response

I am working on soap web service project with Java 7 & Tomcat 7 as container. I need to write code to send a response for a web method call. 
We have two customers which required different parameters in response e.g. for response of customer A, we need to add fields 1.custno, 2.email address, 3.service_no while for customer B we  need to send response fields as 1.custno,2.email_address,3.Phone_number

Now I can create one response class with 4 fields in it & based on a flag I can fill 3 & keep 4th field empty in response. But I am looking for something so that I can send different response params (3 only) based on context or client. 
At present we have a database record which contain information that which client is running this instance & we can take decision based on that.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
Ash